# ajax POST + spring controller parameter passing error

Tags: java, ajax, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I have strange problem with passing an Int param in POST request to the Spring MVC controller.

The thing is that a parameter is passed through POST, but didn't parsed by the controller.

Here is the Code:
**Spring Controller:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("user")
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public JsonResponse AddUser(@RequestBody User user){
        System.out.println(user.getCondoID());
        System.out.println(user.getPassword());
        System.out.println(user.getUsername());

        *** SOME MY STUFF ***
}
```

**User model:**

```
public class User {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private int condo_id;
    private List<String> roles;

    public List<String> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
    public void setRoles(List<String> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public int getCondoID() {
        return condo_id;
    }
    public void setCondoID(int condo_id) {
        this.condo_id = condo_id;
    }
}
```

How do i send **POST in Angular(example):**

```
$scope.choosenCondo.id = "7";
var formData = {
    "username" : $scope.registerUser.email,
    "password" : $scope.registerUser.password,
    "condo_id" : parseInt($scope.choosenCondo.id)
};

var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/api/user/register',
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('input[name="_csrf"]').val(),
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': "1",
        //'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: formData
}

$http(req)
```

So, for `System.out.println(user.getCondoID());` i receive "0" in log.
But the POST data looks like this for example: `{"username":"4t654y54y54y","password":"1q2w3e","condo_id":2}`
so the param is sent in POST. What can be a reason of this trouble?

Comment: Maybe your `getter/setter` for condo_id variable are not following the nomenclature conventions, so condo_id cannot be serialized correclty. Could you try it changing these methods for `getCondo_id()` and `setCondo_id(int condo_id)`? or changing the variable name from condo_id to condoId.

Comment: another guess - User class may need default constructor.

Comment: "Could you try it changing these methods"
change it to what?

Comment: `getCondoID()` -> `getCondo_id()` and `setCondoID(int condo_id)` -> `setCondo_id(int condo_id)`.

Comment: Use proper camelcase for your variables/methods. `int condo_id` would become `Integer condoId` (prefer to use Objects rather then primitives). Next let your IDE generate the getters/setters.

Comment: Also in your POST you do not have a List<String> object. This might be a problem for the jackson parser. In any case try to turn on debug logging to see where the exact problem lies

Answer (score 1):

Your User Model should be like

```
public class User {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private int condo_id;
    private List<String> roles;

    public List<String> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
    public void setRoles(List<String> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public int getCondo_id() {
        return condo_id;
    }

    public void setCondo_id(int condo_id) {
        this.condo_id = condo_id;
    }

    /*
    public int getCondoID() {
        return condo_id;
    }
    public void setCondoID(int condo_id) {
        this.condo_id = condo_id;
    }
    */
}
```

It didn't find the actual setter method to set the value for the property "condo_id".

```
So, for System.out.println(user.getCondoID()); i receive "0" in log.
```

By java nature, primitive value default initialized to 0, so it is printing 0

Comment: `private Integer condo_id;`
Declare as `Interger` thats what helps :)

Comment: When you define as `private Integer condo_id;`, If there is no values coming it will be initialized to null,

Comment: When you define as `private int condo_id;`, If there is no values coming it will throw exception, NULL can not be assigned to primitive type

Comment: value is coming, it wasn't parsed.
`private Integer condo_id;`

this helped